# How to output ovals from a 2d array in Android Studios?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am making a android studios application to play hashi puzzle game. I want to output a 2d array in the grid form, if there is a 0 in the duel iteration I want to output a oval with a 0 in it, and if on the iteration it equals 1 it will output a oval with a 1 ect ect. however when I run the application it only outputs 1 oval in the first position.

```
public class boardView extends View {

public int IslandX;
public int IslandY;

private Canvas canvas;

public boardView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

int gameBoard[][] = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 2, 0, 0, 2}, {2, 0, 3, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2, 0, 2}};
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    Paint Blue = new Paint();
    Blue.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    Blue.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int R = 0; R < 4; R++) {
            if (gameBoard[i][R] == 1) {
                // if the iteration = 1 then..
                IslandX = i;
                IslandY = R;

            }else if (gameBoard[i][R]==0){
                IslandX = i;
                IslandY = R;

            }else if (gameBoard[i][R]==2){
                IslandX = i;
                IslandY = R;
            }
            canvas.drawOval(IslandX, IslandY, 50, 50, Blue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: few notes, **1-** all `if-elseif` is doing the same thing, so whats the point? **2-** you are using i and R which will be 0-4 values, i am not sure if that will draw the grid you are expecting, shifting x,y 1 at a time may not be noticeable on screen?! **the thing is**, the 4 ovals are being drawn but almost on top of each other with a very tiny shifting in coords.

Comment: how would you make them further apart?

Comment: depends on the thing you want to draw, a grid or something, but as a start i would use `i*50` for IslandX and IslandY... see what you get, then play around with the equation until you achieve what you need

Comment: i have tried this, yet it does nothing!